# Why isn't there any native limit preventing a fork bomb?

Tags: operating-systems, vulnerabilities

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85411 (and the [link shared in](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm) ) I know it's possible to avoid  self-duplicating processes known as "fork bomb" on Linux, however, it's only thanks to an user-set limit. I didn't find a similar trick for Windows, and didn't search for Mac OS but I bet it's the same. However, it is sure that these are all natively vulnerable to this old informatic flaw.

So my question: how can something that old still strike today on our modern computers without any kind of natively-implemented defense, when there's ways to avoid that and it's easier than ever ?

Comment: But there [is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469950/2168) a limit?

Comment: @grawity Didn't see that, thanks ! However, though there's a limit preventing the system to completely crash, it still makes the system hanging and partially unusable. Furthermore such security is only on Linux.